# Spring: Error during Creation of a Bean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->

<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="your.intermedix"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>your.intermedix.domain.Contact</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>   

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

      <bean id="fooService" class="your.intermedix.services.ContactSerImpl"/>

</beans>
```

Error thrown

```
2011-01-04 20:32:46.742:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@96e599{/sampleproject,file:/C:/project
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myVaadinApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; neste
eating bean with name 'your.intermedix.MyVaadinApplication': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.B
your.intermedix.services.IContact] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [contactSerImpl, fooService]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:9
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:413)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:735)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2011-01-04 20:32:46.903:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myVaadinApplicati
.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'your.intermedix.MyVaadinApplication': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exceptio
itionException: No unique bean of type [your.intermedix.services.IContact] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [contactSerImpl
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [your.intermedix.services.IContact] is defined: expected
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostP
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:61)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBea
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:978)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$before$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractBe
        at your.intermedix.MyVaadinApplication.<init>(MyVaadinApplication.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:9
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:413)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:735)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2011-01-04 20:32:47.160:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that this:

```
<bean id="fooService" class="your.intermedix.services.ContactSerImpl"/>
```

collides with this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.intermedix"/>
```

I.e. two beans of the same type are created and Spring doesn't know which one to wire.

Comment: @theJava get rid of one or the other. In Spring, there is more than one way to do almost everything. Just make sure you don't do it all at once.

Comment: i removed this one <bean id="fooService" class="your.intermedix.services.ContactSerImpl"/>
, and now my data is not getting saved in database.

Comment: i created a new topic... plz do look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595373/data-not-getting-saved-in-database