# Data not getting saved in database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Here is my bean.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->

<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="your.intermedix"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>your.intermedix.domain.Contact</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>   

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Service class

```
package your.intermedix.services;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import your.intermedix.domain.Contact;
import your.intermedix.services.IContact;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactSerImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IContact {

        public Contact saveContact(Contact contact) {
            System.out.println(contact);
            getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(contact);
            return contact;
        }

        public void hello() {
            System.out.println("Hello Guru");
        }
}
```

My Frontend

```
package your.intermedix;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import your.intermedix.domain.Contact;
import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.Form;
import com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem;
import com.vaadin.terminal.Sizeable;
import com.vaadin.terminal.UserError;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import your.intermedix.domain.ContactValdiation;
import your.intermedix.services.IContact;


/**
 * The Application's "main" class
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
@Controller
public class MyVaadinApplication extends Application implements Button.ClickListener
{

    @Autowired
    private transient IContact icontact;

    private Window window;
    private Button save = new Button("Save", (ClickListener) this);
    private Button cancel = new Button("Cancel", (ClickListener) this);
    private Contact contact = new Contact();
    private Form form = new Form();
    private BeanItem item = new BeanItem(contact);
    private GridLayout ourLayout;


        public void init(){         
            loadForm();
        }

        private void loadForm(){
            window = new Window("InterMedix Application");
            setMainWindow(window);
                final Panel panel = new Panel("Contact Information");
                panel.addStyleName("panelexample");
            // The width of a Panel is 100% by default, make it
            // shrink to fit the contents.
                panel.setWidth(Sizeable.SIZE_UNDEFINED, 0);
                form.setWriteThrough(false);
                form.setInvalidCommitted(false);
                form.setImmediate(true);
                form.setFormFieldFactory(new ContactValdiation());
                form.setRequired(true);
                form.setItemDataSource(item);
                form.setVisibleItemProperties(new Object[] {"name","lastname","email","designation","date","comments"});
                form.setValidationVisibleOnCommit(true);
                form.setFooter(new VerticalLayout());
                // Have a button bar in the footer.
                HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout();
                form.getLayout().addComponent(buttons);
                buttons.addComponent(save);
                buttons.addComponent(cancel);
                panel.addComponent(form);

            window.addComponent(panel);

        }   


        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            if (event.getSource() == save) {
                try {
                    form.commit();
                    icontact.hello();
                    icontact.saveContact(contact);
                }
                 catch (Exception e)    {

                 }
                }
            }
        }
```

The Error below:

> 2011-01-04 21:57:46.331:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@14ce5eb{/sampleproject,file:/C:/projects/sampleproject/src/main/webapp/;file:/C:/projects/sampleproject/target/sampleproject-1.0/;}
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myVaadinApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'user': No unique bean of type [java.lang.Object] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 15: [org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlace
>       holderConfigurer#0, contactSerImpl, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBea
>       nPostProcessor#0, mySessionFactory, myDataSource, org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator, org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor, txManager, messageSource, applicationEventMulticaster]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)

Comment: how do you define `ContactSerImpl ` in spring-context?

Comment: This does everything if i am not wrong <context:component-scan base-package="your.intermedix"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing several things multiple times:

This:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

already includes this:

```
<!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Remove the `<bean>` definitions and try again, perhaps that's the reason.

**Reference: [Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)**

---

**Update:** about your new error:

[`HibernateDaoSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html) needs either a `HibernateTemplate` or a `SessionFactory` as dependency. You have a `SessionFactory`, but Spring can't wire it because by default, Spring doesn't autowire properties, so you need to either manually wire the property or set `<beans default-autowire="byType">` (if you use `byName`, you will have to change your SessionFactory bean definition to `id="sessionFactory"`)

Comment: When i remove either one of them i get error. i have updated the error stuffs

Comment: ??? Don't remove *all* `<bean>` definitions, just the BeanPostProcessor definitions

Comment: should i keep up the annotations like @controller, @service and @transactional

Comment: @theJava keep all `@Transactional` annotations, remove the others from classes you wire via xml (they are hints for `<context:component-scan>` and would cause these classes to be wired twice)

Comment: I have updated my post again, i am getting a weird error which i was not yet

Comment: @theJava I have also added an update, but it duplicates axtavt's answer

Comment: I did not use that, i am following your guidelines alone

Comment: @theJava apparently your application needs a user property, but I can't see one in your class.

Comment: I changed into byName instead of byType and changed the mySessionFactory to sessionFactory

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is caused by the fact that `HibernateDaoSupport` doesn't autowire `SessionFactory` by default, so you need to configure injection of `SessionFactory` explicitly, like this:

```
@Service @Transactional
public class ContactSerImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IContact {
    @Autowired
    public ContactSerImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }
    ...
}
```